# How to avoid message like "expected type 'int', got 'Series' instead" while not turning off the inspection?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Some of my functions do operation between pd.Series/DataFrame and int/float numbers. Message like "expected type 'int', got 'Series' instead" shows up in PyCharm. How to avoid these messages while not turning off the inspection?

For example, in a sample function below. I got a message about x.diff

```
def test(x: pd.Series, n: int):
    y = x.diff() / n
    return y

message is: "Expected type 'int', got 'Series' instead."
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? It indicates an error in your code.

Comment: In the code above, don't think it's an error.

Comment: Put cursor on the highlighted fragment, Alt+Enter, suppress the inspection for the statement

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm determines from the type-hints of the source code that the arguments you pass are incorrect.
***Switching off the inspection completely is not a good solution. Most of the time PyCharm gets it right and this provides useful feedback.***

but if you do it :

1-Go to Settings/Preferences :(

> Ctrl + Alt + S)

2-On the sidebar, click **Inspections**

3-Expand the **Python tab**

4-Scroll down to **Type Checker** and **uncheck** it